# Почему Pycharm не распознаёт .register?

Tags: python, pycharm

```
import reprlib
from collections import abc

RE_WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')


class Sentence:
    def __init__(self, text: str):
        self.text = text
        self._words = RE_WORD.findall(text)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._words)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._words[key]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}(%s)' % reprlib.repr(self.text)


abc.Sequence.register(Sentence)  # type: ignore
sentence = Sentence('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conSecond addiction elit')
print(isinstance(sentence, abc.Sequence))
```

Comment: Что значит "не распознает"? Код выводит True (если конечно добавить забытый import re). Вообще, в этом случае можно было просто отнаследовать `Sentence` от `abc.Sequence`, а не регистрировать "снаружи".

Comment: Pycharm ругается я поставил type: ignore

Comment: У "ругается" есть конкретный текст.

Comment: Unresolved attribute reference 'register' for class 'Sequence'

Comment: Ну, я не вижу тут особой проблемы, если Pycharm предупреждение выдает, но код при этом работает. Либо оставьте как есть с type: ignore, либо вместо регистрации отнаследуйтесь от abc.Sequence, как я писал выше.

Comment: IDE не может найти декларацию `register()` в stub файлах. Проблема известная https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35190/PyCharm-does-not-recognize-register-method-of-abstract-base-classes